# GET method CakePHP search form

Tags: php, cakephp

i have few days using CakePHP and i want to make a simple search form but im stuck i have this:

My Search Form:

```
<?php 

echo $this->Form->create(array('controller' => 'negocios', 'action' => 'buscar', 'type' => 'get'));
echo $this->Form->input('lugar', 
    array('options' => 
        array('City 1', 
            'City 2', 
            'City 3', 
            'City 4', 
            'City 5', 
            'City 6', 
            'City 7',
            'City 8',
            'City 9'
            ), 'empty' => 'All places', 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'selectric'));

echo $this->Form->input('buscador', array('placeholder' => 'Buscar negocios...', 'label' => false));
echo $this->Form->submit('search.png', array('type' => 'button', 'id' => 'buscar', 'div' => false));
echo $this->Form->end();
```

?>

My controller:

```
public function buscar(){

$negocios = array();


if (!empty($this->request->params['Negocio'])) {

    $query = $this->request->params['Negocio']['buscador'];

    $conditions = array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'or' => array(
                'Negocio.nombre LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Negocio.direccion LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Negocio.descripcion LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Negocio.direccion LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Negocio.email LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Negocio.web LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Negocio.facebook LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Negocio.twitter LIKE' => "%$query%",
                'Negocio.categoria LIKE' => "%$query%"
            )
        )
    );

    $negocios = $this->Negocio->find('all', $conditions);
}

$this->set('negocios', $negocios);
debug($this->params);
```

}

And i get nothing in my view im using a foreach(), it was working with POST method, and when i search something i get this in the url:

http://example.com/directorio/negocios/buscar?lugar=0&buscador=this+is+an+example&x=0&y=0

My select in the form use these values 0, 1, 2, 3,... for each instead that i want the name of the city and an url like this:

http://example.com/directorio/negocios/buscar?lugar=City+1&buscador=this+is+an+example

because i have no idea what is X and Y in the url, i guess my problem is the controller and my conditions because im not using nothing for $this->request->params['Negocio']['lugar'];

I hope you can help me or guide me what should i do, thanks.

By the way this is the debug($this->params);

```
object(CakeRequest) {
params => array(
    'plugin' => null,
    'controller' => 'negocios',
    'action' => 'buscar',
    'named' => array(),
    'pass' => array()
)
data => array()
query => array(
    'lugar' => '0',
    'buscador' => 'this is an example',
    'x' => '0',
    'y' => '0'
)
```

Comment: Why not simply using https://github.com/CakeDC/search ?

Comment: Hey @mark i read something about this, but im learning how to use CakePHP so i prefer make it without plugins, but thank you.

Comment: It is no shame (especially as a beginner) to use code of skilled developers or popular plugins. This way you can learn how to do it right. Embrace the code that is available, study it, school yourself in clean and good coding. Better than baking something buggy - which usually happens when you don't exactly know yet how to do certain things. PS: "array('controller' => ..." => the controller part is not effective here - its useless without a "url" key as parent. See the documentation. It is also always a good idea to just post the form it itself, you can omit the whole setup in create() then.

Comment: I understand but i prefer this way, no offense i take all the advice and suggestions, so this should be echo $this->Form->create(array('action' => 'buscar', 'type' => 'get')); ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with

```
$query = $this->params['query']['buscador'];
```

X and Y do not matter.

Regarding `lugar`. Let's say you have an array

```
$lugar = array('City 1', 'City2' ,'City3');
```

In the view, use

echo $this->Form->input('lugar', 
    array('options' => 
        array(array_combine($lugar, $lugar)), 'empty' => 'All places', 'label' => false, 'div' => false, 'class' => 'selectric'));

Then, in the controller, add `$lugar` to the conditions:

```
$query = $this->params['query']['buscador'];
$lugar = $this->params['query']['lugar'];

$conditions = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'or' => array(
            'Negocio.lugar LIKE' => "%$lugar%",
            'Negocio.nombre LIKE' => "%$query%",
             ....
```

Comment: I will try with this, now i have more ideas about what to do, thanks again man.